# What is the exact type of "" when deduced by `auto`?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, c-strings

In this line:

```
auto a = "Hello World";
```

What is the **exact** Type of `a`? I'd guess `char[]` or `const char* const` but I'm not sure.

Comment: This way it decays to `const char*`

Comment: Looks like `const char *`, on my version of g++ (4.8.1), both `typeid(a).name()` and `typeid(const char *).name()` return the same value while `typeid(const char[]).name()` or `typeid(b).name()` (`const char b[] = "Hello World";`) return something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

N4296 2.13.5/8

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. **A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and has static storage duration (3.7).

But since variable is initialized as in your code it is actually `const char*`, you can check it like this.

```
template<typename> struct TD;

int main()
{
   auto a = "Hello World";
   TD<decltype(a)> _;
}
```

Here will be compile error in which you can see the actual type of `TD` instance, something like this with clang

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const char *>'
```

N4296 7.1.6.4

> If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type is
>   determined using the rules for template argument deduction.

```
template<typename> struct TD;

template<typename T>
void f(T) 
{
   TD<T> _;
}

int main()
{
   auto c = "Hello";
   TD<decltype(c)> _;
   f("Hello");
}
```

Both instantiated objects of type `TD` has type `TD<const char*>`.

N4926 14.8.2.1

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it P) with the type of the corresponding
>   argument of the call (call it A) as described below.
>
> If P is not a reference type:
>
> If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the
>   array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of A for
>   type deduction

Comment: *"you can check it like this `TD<decltype(a)> _;`"* - how does that check?  Not only is `TD` incomplete such that it can't be defined, but if that's fixed it would work for any type - see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4469e06eef32b3b9).

Comment: @TonyD the point is that an incomplete type triggers a compiler error which prints out the type used to instantiate this incomplete type. A more convenient solution is `template <class T> void TD() { std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl; }`

Comment: @TonyD it is check. Not define TD. You will se type of TD on compile-time as compile-time error.

Comment: @ForEveR Your comment would also be a good Extension to your answer. That would make the answer explain itself.

Comment: *"triggers a compiler error which prints out the type used to instantiate this incomplete type"* - oh - I guess that's going to be true of any compiler... neat idea.  Cheers.

Comment: I usually write something like this: `struct checker{} check;` and then `a=check;` It will trigger error that `checker` cannot be converted into `X` (where `X` is the type of `a`).  You can also write `check = a;` .. Use whatever reads good enough to you.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've reason to think it'd be implementation or un-defined, can just test:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void f() { std::cout << "other\n"; }
template <> void f<const char*>() { std::cout << "const char*\n"; }
template <> void f<const char* const>()
    { std::cout << "const char* const\n"; }
template <> void f<const char(&)[12]>() { std::cout << "const char[12]\n"; }

int main()
{
    auto a = "Hello World";
    f<decltype(a)>();
}
```

Output:

```
const char*
```

Checking that `++a` compiles is another clue (it does), and while implementation defined `#include <typeinfo>` / `typeid(a).name()` can often help answer such questions.

Change to `auto& a` and you'll see `a` changes to `const char(&)[12]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the type of a using `typeinfo`

```
int main()
{
    auto a = "Hello World";
    std::cout << "type is: " << typeid(a).name() << '\n';
}
```

on gcc it will print

> pi is: PKc

which stands for pointer to constant char
If you're in Windows the output will be a lot more readable, but you get used to this syntax too.

If you know more or less which type you a re looking for, you can also check if two types are equivalent with:

```
#include <typeinfo>
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, decltype(a)>::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Use c++filt to demangle names. Anyways, typeid isn't the best to show types as it discards cv-qualifiers.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know that, I got confused by the fact that   `char* b = const_cast<char*>(a);
    std::cout << "type is: " << typeid(b).name() << '\n';` outputs `Pc`

Comment: I would not recommend typeid.name which can return wrong types as Scott Meier explains in http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf (Slide 32)